# Can anyone identify this biplane from a TV show?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image: Unknown Biplane]

Could someone help identify this biplane from a TV show, please? No other scene / camera angle is available though.

Comment: could you at least name the tv show and episode?

Comment: Sorry, it's "Falcon Crest" # 075 <4.07>, but I thought it's no help because this is the only visible angle in a very short segment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My vote would be a [Waco UPF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waco_F_series) without the engine cowl:

[image]
<sup>Source: [American Power Museum](https://americanairpowermuseum.com/2014/01/01/waco-upf7/)</sup>

Looks like the one in the OP post has a different engine in it or at least a relocated cooler, but the struts and windscreen design look very similar. (Struts on the right side are distorted by perspective, look at the ones on the left). Gear bracing is also pretty close.

Comment: Looks like a direct hit +1! Struts, gear, windshield all fit. Only the air intake is most likely an oil cooler.

Comment: I originally called it a cooler but second guessed myself...

Comment: @TJP Please don't add "thank you" as a comment. If you want to thank someone, up-vote the answer. If you think this answer fully answers your question, you can also mark it as accepted (using the tick mark next to it).